# Get text content of an HTML element using XPath?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, html-parsing

See this html

```
<div>
    <p>
    <span class="abc">Monitor</span> <b>$300</b>
    </p>
    <a href="/add">Add to cart</a>
</div>
<div>
    <p>
    <span class="abc">Keyboard</span> $20 
    </p>
    <a href="/add">Add to cart</a>
</div>
```

Using xpath I want to parse `Monitor $300` and `Keyboard $20`. I use this xpath

```
 //div[a[contains(., "Add to cart")]]/p/text()
```

But it selects `<span class="abc">Monitor</span> <b>$300</b>`. I don't want the tags. How do I get only the text?

Comment: `text()` should never select elements. What XML parser are you using?

Comment: @choroba `scrapy.selector.lxmlsel.HtmlXPathSelector`

Comment: How do you access the value? In the DOM Level 3 word you would select the `p` elements with e.g. `//div[a[contains(., "Add to cart")]]/p` and then access the `textContent` property to get plain text contents.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I am using `XPathSelector`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You want to select all *descendant* text, not just child text:

```
//div[a[contains(., "Add to cart")]]/p//text()
```

Note the double slash between `p` and `text()` there.

This potentially will also include a lot of inter-tag whitespace though, you you'll need to clean that up. Example using `lxml`:

```
>>> import lxml.etree as ET
>>> tree = ET.fromstring('''<div>
... <div>
...     <p>
...     <span class="abc">Monitor</span> <b>$300</b>
...     </p>
...     <a href="/add">Add to cart</a>
... </div>
... <div>
...     <p>
...     <span class="abc">Keyboard</span> $20 
...     </p>
...     <a href="/add">Add to cart</a>
... </div>
... </div>''')
>>> tree.xpath('//div[a[contains(., "Add to cart")]]/p//text()')
['\n    ', 'Monitor', ' ', '$300', '\n    ', '\n    ', 'Keyboard', ' $20 \n    ']
>>> res = _
>>> [txt for txt in (txt.strip() for txt in res) if txt]
['Monitor', '$300', 'Keyboard', '$20']
```

Comment: Wow! that double `//` saves my day

Comment: Glad that worked for you. :-) I was just making sure you understand where the whitespace comes from and how to clean it up.