# Python: xpath to grab text from element in span

Tags: html, xml, python-2.7, xpath

I have the following HTML:

```
<span class="time" data-time="2014-11-06T22:00:00.000+0000">10'</span>
```

And I am getting to it with python code like this:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

page=requests.get('http://www.url.com/data')
tree=html.fromstring(page.text)
empty=tree.xpath('//*[@id="stuff"]/div[1]/div[6]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/span/text()')
```

The trouble that I am having is that this returns an empty list for this particular element. The element is a timer which is dynamically updated on the site, and it doesn't look like the text() call is doing anything.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Got it: added an extra '/' before the text() call. So it read, ".../div[3]/span//text()" which selects all descendant text. After spending quite some time searching (before the post, believe you me), I did end up finding help here [Get text content of an HTML element using XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631590/get-text-content-of-an-html-element-using-xpath)

I will leave this up to help others in the future.

Comment: Does anyone know why the extra slash is required in this case?